# Add User Via php

Tags: php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "Doing ``"."useradd $username -p '$password' "."'' as ".get_current_user()."..<br/>";
passthru("/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/sbin/useradd $username -p '$password'" );
echo "finished ok<br>";
?>
<p>
<a href="index.html">Go back and try again</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have no idea how to sanitize that properly. Do you really need it? Oh and add a `$return_var` parameter to see what sudo returns to you.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest to sanitize the input ($_POST[])  before using.  Even more in your case that you execute shell command with it.

Answer (score 2):

I can exploit that in a few moments:

Set username to "; newcommand here to pwn your box" or " || other command"

YOU NEED to sanitize the values prior to running this.

Using strpos and check for possible exploits.